# Windows 11 battery life issue

Tags: laptop, windows-11, battery-life

In early 2022, I bought a new Lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen2 with an AMD Ryzen 7 4700 u. It had Windows 10 pre-installed, and I immediately upgraded to Windows 11. Although the manufacturer promised a battery life of 8 to 10 hours, the battery life after the upgrade was at best 2 to 3 hours.

To improve the battery life, I tried all the tips and hacks I could find. I installed all Windows 11 updates and manufacturer updates. But nothing had an impact.

Some research on Google ([link][1], [link][2]) showed me that it seems to be a global issue with Windows 11.

Finally, I downgraded to Windows 10, and the battery life was as I expected. I get about 7 to 8 hours.

I quite liked the new UI of Windows 11 and the improved usability, but battery life for me is more important.

So finally, my question is: Is there any information from Microsoft or any manufacturer about this issue and when it will be fixed?

[1]: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-insider-program/battery-draining-issue-after-installaiton-of-windows-11/m-p/2752654
  [2]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/615704/windows-11-horrible-battery-life.html

Comment: Battery life on my Lenovo ThinkPad X1 with Windows 11 Pro is very good. Did you update all your drivers including BIOS with Lenovo System Update?

Comment: "I tried all the tips and hacks I could find." Not very specific. Did you set the power options to lower performance to increase battery life?

Comment: Yes, I have set the power options to lower performance and I updated the BIOS with Lenovo System Update.